Qt6 QAbstractListModel - constructor with two arguments - qml Element is not creatable
I try to use a kind of source code for Qt6, which in principle worked with Qt5: I want to make a graphical output for my system of hardcore particles. In the constructor of the QAbstractListModel I have two arguments: System *system, QObject *parent=0
I think the *system argument is the reason, why in the qml the item Hardcore_Entrymodel{} is not creatable (QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component).
How can I make my qml File work again?
I ported the model stuff from a sheepflock simulation with qt5 which in principle worked. Now, with the new hardcore model and with qt6 the qml file errors. I did a recherche in the web and got a feeling, it errors because of the two argument constructor.
The Header File of Hardcore_Entrymodel:
class Hardcore_Entrymodel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Hardcore_Entrymodel(System*, QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    void populate();

    QHash<int, QByteArray> mPropertyNames;

    enum mParticleProperties{
        type = Qt::UserRole,
        iparticle = Qt::UserRole+1,
        size_semimajoraxis = Qt::UserRole+2,
        size_semiminoraxis = Qt::UserRole+3,
        x_mid_pxl = Qt::UserRole+4,
        y_mid_pxl = Qt::UserRole+5,
        xy_angle_degree = Qt::UserRole+6,
        typecolor = Qt::UserRole+7,
    };

    Q_INVOKABLE void doNewStep();
    Q_INVOKABLE void stepReady();
    Q_INVOKABLE int returnWindowLx();
    Q_INVOKABLE int returnWindowLy();
    Q_INVOKABLE int returnSteptime_ms();

    bool isNewStep();
    void setIsNewStep(bool newS);


protected:
    virtual QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
private:
    System *hardcoresystem;
    int nparticles;
    InitQtView initqtview;
    QList<std::tuple<std::string, int,int,int,int,int, QColor> > mDatas;
    bool newStep;

signals:
    void newStepDoing();
    void newStepReady();

public slots:
    void onNewStepDone();
};


The main function:
#include <QObject>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "Hardcore_InitClass.h"
#include "Hardcore_Entrymodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Hardcore_InitClass initClass(argc, argv);
    System system;
    initClass.return_Hardcoresystem_single(&system);
    system.writeParametersFile();

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

        // register the type DataEntryModel
        // under the url "org.example" in version 1.0
        // under the name "DataEntryModel"
    qmlRegisterType<Hardcore_Entrymodel>("org.hardcoresystem", 1, 0, "Hardcore_Entrymodel");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qt/qml/Main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

And the first part of the qml file:
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
//import QtQuick.Layouts 2.2
import QtQml.Models 2.12
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0

import org.hardcoresystem 1.0

Window {
    id: appwindow
    visible: true
    width: hardcoreentrymodel.returnWindowLx()
    height: hardcoreentrymodel.returnWindowLx()


    Rectangle{
        id: hardcoresystemrectangle
        anchors.left: appwindow.left
        anchors.top: appwindow.top
        width: appwindow.width
        height: appwindow.height
        color: "white"
    }

    Hardcore_Entrymodel{
        id: hardcoreentrymodel
        //onNewPathDoing: console.log("New Path doing ...\n")
        //onNewPathReady: {console.log("New Path ready ...\n")}
        //onDataChanged:  console.log("DataChanged received")
      }

    Timer {
        id: steptimer
        interval: Number(hardcoreentrymodel.returnSteptime_ms())
        //interval: 100
        repeat: true
        running: true
        triggeredOnStart: true
        onTriggered: {hardcoreentrymodel.doNewStep()}
       }

    Item{
        id: partilcesitem
        width: hardcoresystemrectangle.width
        height: hardcoresystemrectangle.height
        anchors.left: hardcoresystemrectangle.left
        anchors.top: hardcoresystemrectangle.top
        Repeater {

[...]

kind regards,
Tobias

In Qt6, I would recommend using QML_ELEMENT to define your types.

Define this contructor: Hardcore_Entrymodel(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QAbstractListModel(parent) { }

I need the System* argument, because it is the actual simulation and Hardcore_Entrymodel is only some kind of wrapper for this ...

Insertion of QML_ELEMENT didn't made any difference:
class Hardcore_Entrymodel : public QAbstractListModel
{
Q_OBJECT
QML_ELEMENT

This code also didn't work in Qt5.

QML requires that components that can be constructed with 0 or 1 explicit parameters. In the latter case, the first argument must be QObject* parameter. The constructor choices you have are:

Hardcore_Entrymodel(QObject *parent = nullptr)
Hardcore_Entrymodel(QObject *parent = nullptr, System* system = nullptr);
Provide two constructors.

Personally, I recommend you go with 1 and remove the System* from your constructor since your solution requires you to instantiate and make System* only available to one of your model instances.
Since your model is creatable, I feel that you need the System* to be available to all your models, so therefore, I feel your System* should be a static member. Doing so, means that it is initializable without an instance of your model.
// Hardcore_Entrymodel.h
class Hardcore_Entrymodel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Hardcore_Entrymodel(QObject *parent = nullptr);
public:
    // Static Methods
    static void SetSystem(System* value) { g_hardcoresystem = value; } 
    static System* GetSystem() { return g_hardcoresystem; }

private:
    // Static Member
    static System *g_hardcoresystem;
};

Initialize your static member...
// Harcode_Entrymodel.cpp
System* Hardcore_Entrymodel::g_hardcodesystem = nullptr;

In your main.cpp you can populate your static member without needing to invoke the constructor.
/// main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    System system;
    Hardcore_Entrymodel::SetSystem(&system);
    // ...


Dear Stephen,
can this really work, if I make some Hardcore_Entrymodel::SetSystem(&sytem) in the main? I thought Qt works like that, that the Hardcore_Entrymodel class is contsructed by some default constructor by qmlRegisterType in some moc, such that it is independent by that what happens in the main. I think by this I had two independent instances of Hardcore_Entrymodel, one by main and one by qt framework ...

Dear Stephen, the static trick did not work:
error: cannot call member function ‘void Hardcore_Entrymodel::setSystem(System*)’ without object
15 |     Hardcore_Entrymodel::setSystem(&system);

Should I make System* hardcoresystem as static variable for all and not only as class member?

My mistake. The getters and setters need to be static methods

With static getters and setters its the same error as with global static variable: the initialization of the System* hardcoresystem fails in the Qt framework (see upper comment of me). After there are 8 Particles in the system object in the main function, there are zero Particles in the object created by qmlRegisterType. I think some strange "moc" compiler encapsulates the classes in some virtualization process. Can I define virtual class members or is "virtual" part of the definition of the class member?

From Stephen Quans idea, I made hardcoresystem to a static variable for all:
static System *hardcoresystem;

class Hardcore_Entrymodel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT

public:
[..]

and in main:
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
Hardcore_InitClass initClass(argc, argv);
System system;
initClass.return_Hardcoresystem_single(&system);
system.writeParametersFile();

hardcoresystem= &system;

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

[...]
Now, I think the Qt stuff should work. But, I have still to debug the communication between the qml file and the QAbstractListModel. This will take a bit time. But, thanks until here!
Tobias

OK, for this case, the initialization of the System fails: If I print out the number of particles, first there are 8 Particles from the main function, but from the System of the qmlRegisterType there are zero Particles (thats why it errors now). So even if hardcoresystem is a static variable, it does not overtake it to the Qt6 moc version of Hardcore_Entrymodel - so there must be a way to give System* as Constructor argument, otherwise my code will not work. But it had even work for Qt5 )-:
